# Loading Unicode or UTF-8 characters into file datastore in Oracle Data Integrator (ODI)

Tags: character-encoding, oracle-data-integrator

How do I load Arabic characters from an Oracle table into a flat file in ODI 10g. 
I used the **"LKM SQL to File Append"** to load data to a flat file. But I believe that it is creating the file in ANSI encoding. This is causing all special characters to appear as question marks "?" in the flat file. This is the only LKM module I found on the tool that loads table to a file.

Additionally I also tried writing UTF-8 & Unicode in the "Format" field under the "columns" tab of the file data store model. But this didn't work.

Is there any way I can **create flat with Unicode/UTF8 encoding** using oracle data integrator?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to create new File Data Server and setting the Encoding setting to 'UTF8'? 
 Try this instructions: [Workin with Files, ODI](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/odi/ODIKM/files.htm#ODIKM466)